# Additional conditions tags to work

Tags: conditional-tags

Im trying to get this simple condition tag to work . Im having no luck

```
// If we are logged in, and NOT an admin and NOT on specific page...
if ( is_user_logged_in() & !is_admin() ) & !is_page('account') ) {
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/account/') === FALSE AND strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === FALSE AND ! is_user_logged_in() === FALSE) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Count the brackets, you've got an extra one:

```
//                                     ↓ here
if ( is_user_logged_in() & !is_admin() ) & !is_page('account') ) {
```

Also, you should use double ampersands in conditions like this. So:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_admin() && !is_page('account') ) {
```

Comment: No Luck function still doesn't work on account page